# Start a lightweight web-server using Swift to receive OAuth1.0 callback in iOS App

Tags: java, ios, iphone, swift, oauth

I'm a newbie in Swift (and iPhone dev). I'm working on a project where I need to build an iOS (using swift) mobile client to demonstrate **OAuth1.0 (3-legged flow)**.

I'm not finding any concrete solution to start a server using swift. I need to pass a **call-back endpoint** to the **request_token** url so that my program can receive the **oauth_verifierId**.

I found the following close solutions (libs) from net, but either lack of examples/docs or due to my less exp on swift, things are not in place yet.

- https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer  - No/less concrete example (not sure how to import this in swift project)
- https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer - Looks good but not
  getting any e2e solution. I want to avoid Obj-C lib in my Swift project.
- https://github.com/glock45/swifter

Actually, I don't need a wrapper like above. It would be best if I could write a Java equivalent like following.

```
ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(7000);
Socket remote = s.accept();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    remote.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(remote.getOutputStream());

String str = null;
while (!str.equals("")){
  str = in.readLine();
  if(str.startsWith("GET")){
      String[] splitStr = str.split("&");
      for(String s1 : splitStr){
          if(s1.startsWith("oauth_verifier")){
              String verifierId = s1.split("=")[1];
              System.out.println("VerifierId - " + verifierId);
          }
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think my answer would a little bit late, just put a sign here for later comers.

If you are about to use GCDWebServer:

1. `pod "GCDWebServer", "~> 3.0"` in your Podfile, then `pod install`, `pod update`.
2. Put a file named `APP_NAME-Bridging-Header.h` in SOME_PATH, put these lines below the #define statement:

   ```
   #import "GCDWebServer.h"
   #import "GCDWebServerDataResponse.h"
   ```
3. Go Project Name -> Build Settings -> Search for `bridging` -> update `Objective-C Bridging Header` to `$(SRCROOT)/SOME_PATH/APP_NAME-Bridging-Header.h`.
4. Now the Objective-C library is globally imported, you could use it everywhere.
5. Use this line of code to instantiate a GCDWebServer instance:

   ```
   let webServer = GCDWebServer()
   ```

Now play it with yourself :)